# Create an anchor without having it displayed in the url

Tags: javascript, html

So I have this page which has 3-4 anchors and whenever I click the button to jump to the section I want, the url should remain the same (without adding #anchor).
I googled this but I couldn't find anything that works and I'm still learning JS so I don't have the knowledge to do this.

Comment: If you do not have the knowledge I would suggest you do some research and learn. You can achieve this multiple ways but it all depends on which method you would like to use.

Comment: @NewToJS, the user is new, why not show a few examples and give a little knowledge. After all thats partly what this site is about albeit I partly agree with your statement

Comment: @Jay Because showing multiple examples could then be seen as a tutorial rather than a solution. This question does not really have a specific issue with existing source code.

Comment: Good point, perhaps that should have been the comment then? `Can you provide a concise verifiable example which we can use to attempt to diagnose your issue`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you mean, Perhaps you can edit your question to show us what you have already tried. Anchors are how the browser knows where to scroll to, if you want to achieve the same thing but without changing the anchor in the address bar you can try something like this on click:

`elmnt.scrollIntoView();`

See also: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_scrollintoview.asp